# Solutions of the Laplace Equation in spherical coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, spherical-coordinates, laplacian

I would like some help with the following problem. Thanks for any help in advance.

Use spherical coordinates to find all solutions of the Laplace equation ∆u(x)=0, u∈Ω⊂R3 that depend only on the radial variable r = |x| in the two following cases: (i)Ω is a ball|x|< a and (ii)Ω is the set defined by|x|>a

If I am only looking at solutions of the Laplace equation that depend on r alone, then my solution is u=A+B(1/r), but the I am unsure how to make use of the two cases.

Comment: If $u$ depends only on $r$ what will the derivatives with respect to $\theta$ and $\phi$ be?

Comment: @TylerHG. They will be zero.

Comment: @TylerHG: I am also unsure how to make use of cases.